# GCP CloudBuild Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

How can I add a custom message to Cloud Build logs?

I've tried using the bash entrypoint with the Docker builder (for example) and echoing some strings, but they don't appear in the build logs. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the builder image you're using has `bash` in it. I tested this [code](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts#running_inline_bash_scripts) and replaced the `gcloud` builder with `docker` and it is working fine. Here's an example code:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-eEuo'
  - 'pipefail'
  - '-c'
  - |-
    if (( $(date '+%-e') % 2 )); then
      echo "today is an odd day"
    else
      echo "today is an odd day, with an even number"
    fi
```

And here's the Logs:

[image]